# Shared element transition from circular ImageView to rectangular ImageView

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-imageview, shared-element-transition

I have two Activities: Activity A and Activity B. Activity A contains a view hierarchy with a circular `ImageView` in the center that looks like the following:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_profile"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_profile_image"/>
```

Activity B is a basic `FrameLayout` that contains a single, rectangular `ImageView` with the same `transitonName`. The goal: when clicking on the `CircleImageView` in Activity A, I want to transition into an expanded, fullscreen view of the image in Activity B. Going back to Activity A should reverse this transition.

I can get a transition to work using the following, basic scene transition:

```
profileImageView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
            profileImageView, getString(R.string.transition_profile_image));
    startActivity(ActivityB.getStartIntent(this, imageUrl),
            options.toBundle());
});
```

Using this code, Activity B's rectangular `ImageView` overlays on top of the `CircleImageView` and then grows to fill the screen. It looks like the circle blinks into a rectangle. The transition of the image should instead perform some sort of transform animation from a circle to a rectangle. Anyone familiar with how to achieve this?

Comment: Still working on a solution for this.

Comment: Hey Ryan, any update on this? were you able to achieve this?

Comment: Hey @JennoRichiBenat. Unfortunately not. Due to time, I had to settle for a animation-less transition. My plan is to return to this when I get more time to investigate a solution.